# Integration of console window with GUI using TkInter

Tags: python, user-interface, console, tkinter, integration

I have a python script that runs the GUI which is coded using Tkinter.
Problem is when i run the script, there are 2 windows opened. One is the GUI and other is the black console window. 
I need to integrate both the windows so that when I start the script only one window appears.
Any ideas are much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Rename your Python script as `.pyw` (not `.pyc`). This will tell the invoker to to instantiate a console window. [Source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=338601)

Note however, this will work for non-GUI based scripts too which can cause undesireqable behaviour - such as not being able to see your script.

Comment: That will work but I need the console window to see the output as well.
That's the reason need to Integrate it inside the GUI Window.

Answer (score 0):

(I am pretty sure there is a better way, but) one way is to change the .pyc object file extension to .pyw and the console will not appear when you launch your GUI using the .pyw file.

Comment: That will work but I need the console window to see the output as well.
That's the reason need to Integrate it inside the GUI Window.